# Trying to create a plugin in rails (2.3.5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am currently working in a old version of rails(2.3.5) and ruby(1.8.7) just followed the rails guideto create plugin, when running the

> rake
>   command it shows the following error!

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby -I"lib:lib:test" "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/yaffle_test.rb"
"test/core_ext_test.rb" 
-- create_table(:hickwalls, {:force=>true})-> 0.3919s
-- create_table(:wickwalls, {:force=>true})-> 0.3297s
-- create_table(:woodpeckers, {:force=>true})-> 0.3370s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()-> 0.0005s
-- assume_migrated_upto_version(0)-> 0.0002s
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
`gem_original_require': no such file to load -- ./test/../rails/init.rb 
(MissingSourceFile)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
`require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib
/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
from ./test/test_helper.rb:34:in `load_schema'
from ./test/yaffle_test.rb:7
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib
/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `load'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib 
rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib
/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib
/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5

rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/bin/ruby -I"lib:lib:test" 
"/usr...]
```